# Navbar dropdown menu not appearing

Tags: html, css

Currently trying to implement the w3schools responsive navbar found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

It is somewhat working, however on small screens, the dropdown menu does not appear. Instead, the last item on the list is in its place. I am not sure what's going on but I feel like I'm missing a key aspect of this. Code below, any advice is appreciated!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mynav");
  if (x.className === "nav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav";
  }
}
```

```css
  .nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(20px + .2vw);
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 10000000;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: calc(7.75px + .25vw);
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background: #e1e1e1;
  color: black;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .nav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="mynav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class='pull-left'>
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">Tools</a>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pull-right">
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this link in the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

        <div class="container">
          <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
          <a href="#news">Tools</a>

          <a href="#contact" class="left">Contact</a>
          <a href="#about" class="left">About</a>

          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>

    </div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.left {
  float: right !important;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .left{
    float: left !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
    .left{
    float: left !important;
    display: block;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: while that did add the drop down menu, it seems to have just slapped it somewhat in the middle, and the menu itself is split into two parts? Here's some screencaps https://imgur.com/a/fbL8bIu

Comment: Correct the answer check it and let me know if it does work